# Photoelectric current - changing energy of a photon

Tags: electric-current, voltage, photoelectric-effect

I already checked the similar topics in here. I was told that changing a photon's energy doesn't affect $i_{max}$, but it changes $i_0$. But I also see from topics in here that people say that photoelectric current is independent from a photon's energy. Is that true or false, and why?
[image: Diagram]

Comment: There is a bit of a twist here. The photons must have enough energy to create a photoelectron.

Comment: What is the twist ? It already has from vcutoff voltage to infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current depends on intensity and IS independent of the photons energy. For example if you only have 100 photons with enough energy to kick out electrons, that’s the maximum current you will get. If you have 100 photons, with much more energy, that still the maximum current you can get it. With only 100 photons you will never get more current than that. No matter how much energy they have.

Comment: That is okay but : imagine that we are sending only 1 photon and asume anode catch that electron. Also let electron hit the anode in 2 sec. After that let’s do the same but increase photons energy. This will cause increasing Ek aldo speed. Thus electron is going to hit anode <2 sec. Then wouldn’t current increase ?

Comment: Either way you look at it, increasing the number of photons/electrons per second is increasing the intensity.